# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `rows` of type `object` supplied to `ForwardRef(DataGrid)`, expected `array`

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Good day! I was wondering why I didnt display data on my grid table eventhough I can see or received data from my api response, I just wondering whats wrong on my code. here is my current code and please see my return data below, thanks

```
const UserModule = () => {

  const logHeader = [
    { field: 'id', headerAlign: 'left', headerName: 'ID', hide: true, width: 50 },
    { field: 'firstname', headerAlign: 'left', headerName: 'First Name', width: 130 },
    { field: 'lastname', headerAlign: 'left', headerName: 'Last Name', sortable: true, width: 110 },
    { field: 'status', headerAlign: 'left', headerName: 'Status', width: 80 },

  ]


  const [transactionLogData, setTransactionLogData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    WorkflowApi.getTransactionLogForRevenueOfficer().then(logs => {

        const newLogs = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(logs).map( ([k,v]) =>  {
              return [k, {
                ...v,
                id: v._id
              }] // I think the problem is here
        }))  
        console.log("newLogs: ", newLogs)
        setTransactionLogData(newLogs)
    })

  })
  ....
return (
  <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Box ref={componentRef}>
             <RecordTable
                  columns={logHeader}
                  rows={transactionLogData}>
             </RecordTable>
         </Box>
  </Grid>
  )
}
```

//RecordTable.js

```
const RecordTable = (props) => {

    const { columns, rows } = props

    useEffect(async () => {

    }, [rows])

//This type of array did my RecordTable component expects

// const sampleRows = [
//     {
//       "_id": 458,
//       "LastUpdateDate": "2022-02-10",
//       "status": "Approved",
//       "firstname": "Yuno",
//       "lastname": "Santiago",
//       "id": 458
//     }
// ]
    return(
            <DataGrid
                ....
                columns={columns}
                rows={rows}
                ....
            />
    )
}
```

response i received from my api

```
{
    "_id": 458,
    "LastUpdateDate": "2022-02-10",
    "status": "Approved",
    "firstname": "Yuno",
    "lastname": "Santiago",
    "id": 458
}
```

this is the error i get

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop rows of type object supplied to ForwardRef(DataGrid), expected array.`

Update after i remove the  **Object.fromEntries**

```
const newLogs = Object.entries(logs).map( ([k,v]) =>  {
                  return [k, {
                    ...v,
                    id: v._id
                  }] // I think the problem is here
            })
```

i received this error

**Uncaught Error: MUI: The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique `id` property.**

Comment: The API is sending an object not an array, as array must be between [ ]

Comment: can you please help me with this? @PauloFernando

Answer (score 1):

check your `rows` props, it highly possible is empty object at first render.
To do so, you just `console.log({rows})` and see the value printed in browser

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the Object.fromEntries, the result of this method is always an object, not an array. Try to remove the Object.fromEntries, and leave only the Object.entries

Comment: after i remove the `Object.fromEntries`, I received this error `Uncaught Error: MUI: The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique `id` property.`

Comment: Hmm, indeed, the Object.entries() breaks the object into an array of key/value pairs. It wouldn't work. Try to use only ...logs.map...

Comment: and put the results of `console.log("newLogs: ", newLogs)`

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem is that I put the column content in another file.
I just put it in the app component and it solves the problem.

It creates an object if the column is in another file,
try to put your recordtable component in the same component(userModule I guess)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33383377)